# How do you export a jpeg with a selective compression mask from Photoshop CC 2014?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, jpg, compression

In fireworks, I can select parts of an image to keep at a lower compression (85) when exporting, leaving the rest of the image to be compressed at the higher setting (60). I cannot find that option in Photoshop CC 2014, but have found some articles that use Photoshop 6 to export such a jpeg. How does one create an image with areas of higher compression and areas of lower compression within Photoshop CC 2014?

Comment: AFAIK, that option was removed in Ps CS4. However, there are JPEG optimizers that will entirely automate the process (I use JPEGmini — the 20 images/day "trial" version is free; it's $20 for the full single-user version — but it's not the only option); they'll do selective compression based on the actual image detail.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rogers! Seems crazy that this would be taken out, but that's all I'm left with too. I do some work with digital advertising, and the IAB has some pretty stringent rules about the sizes of ads. Squeezing every bit out of images is a must. Again, I appreciate your response!